# Who is the person with purple hairs at the end of Kai season of Higurashi?

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

At the very end of Kai season of Higurashi no Naku Koro Ni, there's a woman telling child Takano not to leave home. She has the same voice as Furude Rika. Is she Furude Rika?

[image]

If she is, is she a time traveller of some sort?

Comment: She is [Frederica Bernkastel](http://whentheycry.wikia.com/wiki/Frederica_Bernkastel), whom I can't really explain well since I only watch the anime. However, she is related to Furude Rika (read as Frederica).

Comment: Wow, thanks. Does this character appear in Rei season, or do you know if it is related to the game?